# CiviCRM hosting for small member based org

Tags: civicrm

I am researching running Drupal 7 & CiviCRM for a new client that needs a CRM solution.

Specs:

- ~200 members
- recurring memberships
- membership payments
- bulk email to members

I am considering CiviCRM with Webform integration, but the client has budgetary issues for hosting.

Have users here successfully run CiviCRM in a **shared** hosting environment, as opposed to a VPS?

And is CiviMail the main resource consumer, or is **any** CiviCRM installation likely going to need VPS hosting to run without problems?

Assuming CiviMail **is** the main resource issue, can one use an external bulk mail tool with CiviCRM (e.g. MailChimp) instead of CiviMail? If so, will this take the burden off the host and mean a VPS isn't necessary to run CiviCRM?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) We don't do hosting recommendations here as they don't fit into the Q+A format. For a better idea of what sorts of questions we do answer, please have a look through the [help]. Thanks

Comment: I think some aspects of the questions posed are reasonable. Points 1, 2 and 5 seem fine to me.

Comment: I also think some aspects are legitimate. And the question is more about what kind of hosting is feasible than an emphasis on specific companies. The questions can be answered generically and have value.

Comment: The OP is welcome to edit it so it's a single, specific, objective question per the site guidelines. If you spot that happening and the question is still closed, please either flag it for re-opening or ping me

Comment: We're not concerned with hosting _companies_ as such @lcdservices, we don't do hosting recommendations for hardware/software either. Too broad and based on too many unknown factors

Comment: I still feel the question qualifies as to broad. 1) There's essentially three different questions; 2) the shared/VPS question doesn't make sense. A high end shared hosting setup could be more powerful than a cheap VPS, so I don't even know how one _could_ answer the second question;
3) All the questions are about _CiviCRM_, and non off them about Drupal as far as I can tell. I don't know a lot about CiviCRM, so I could be wrong though.